# WPF DataGrid RowDetails with Button for only one row

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

i have a DataGrid with collapsed RowDetails:

```
<Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="Collapsed"/>
```

And I have a Button with fallowing code to open the RowDetails:

```
private void ButtonShowHide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (var vis = sender as Visual; vis != null; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as Visual)
            if (vis is DataGridRow)
            {
                var row = (DataGridRow)vis;
                row.DetailsVisibility = row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
                break;
            }
    }
```

[Screenshot of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH8Fi.png)

When I click the button it also opens and closes the RowDetails.
But now I want the RowDetails to be closed as soon as I open the next ones.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF datagrid collapse details row on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354603/wpf-datagrid-collapse-details-row-on-click)

Comment: Just get the other rows and collapse their details pane. Only set the current/selected row's details to visible. By default, if you define the DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate, the details are only visible for the selected row and automatically collapsed when the selected row changes. You can assign a value to the DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplateSelector property in case you need to define multiple templates.

Comment: Do it with Binding to a VM property rather than operating on the UI property directly. So you don't have to acrobatically search the sibling row in the Visual Tree. And in that VM property handle the visibility toggle of the neighboring row.

Comment: @lidqy Thank you!! I couldn't see the forest for the trees anymore. That was exactly the solution :)

With a public DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode in the ViewModel it worked and I was able to remove the annoying UI codebehind. Placed in the right positions it now runs smoothly.